# CUDA 8.0 and newest NVIDIA drivers

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, cuda

Is it possible to use CUDA with open source 378 or 380 driver? Installation always forces proprietary nvidia-375 to be used. Unfortunately this driver contains a bug for my video card and it's undesirable to use it. Howsoever I tried to replace nvidia-375 with newer one, it always entails purging CUDA. So, is there any way out of this?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to just reinstall CUDA after your selected Nvidia driver is in place?  That seems to be the easiest approach.

Comment: @ubfan1 The problem is whenever I install CUDA toolkit it makes nvidia-375 to be default driver. If after that I try to replace the driver --- CUDA is going to be deleted.

Comment: Have you tried the Nvidia-375.66 from the standard repositories which just downloaded today on my machine and fixed the artifact problem with the ...375.39 driver?

Comment: @ubfan1 oh, did not know that it had been fixed. Thanks!